# ASP.net MVC Routing Throws Exceptions as Normal Behavour?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, exception, routes

I was debugging my current project (ASP.net MVC 1.0 project)
and stumbled upon slightly disturbing behavour.

It seems that when the router is hunting for a referenced partial view
aka

```
<%Html.RenderPartial("AccountListControl", ViewData["AccountList"]); %>
```

It cycles through it's default locations until it finds the correct spot.
So it checks "Views\Shared\AccountListControl"
and checks "Views\Home\AccountListControl"
etc

Once it finds a match - all is good.
Bad locations are identified by the web exception thrown in each case.

*Is there a significant performance cost for all of these exceptions?*

Should I modify the code to be more explicit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that in Release mode there [are no exceptions thrown and view locations are cached](http://blog.dynatrace.com/2009/04/23/aspnet-mvc-htmlhelperrenderpartial-caches-resolved-names-in-release-mode/) so there is no need to be more explicit.